# Use of FrameLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

- What is the exact use of FrameLayout in Android?
- Where can we use it?
- What is the difference between Frame and Relative layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**LinearLayout** arranges elements side by side either horizontally or vertically(rows vs columns).

**RelativeLayout** is a layout manager that helps you arrange your UI elements based on some rule. You can specify things like: align this to parents left edge, place this to the left/right of this elements etc.

**AbsoluteLayout** is for absolute positioning i.e. you can specify exact co-ordinates where the view should go.

**FrameLayout** allows placements along Z-axis. That is you can stack your view elements one above the other.

Answer (score 2):

As per my opinion

1. **RelativeLayout** can use to make sure views lineup correctly in relation to each other.
2. **FrameLayout** is very similar except it's only using gravity to put display it's views (with no relation).

For more information, please check this official page:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#CommonLayouts